# React component bundle for consuming by browser and node (react hooks issue)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, react-hooks

I have seriously headache because of this issue.

Source code - https://github.com/marekkobida/stackoverflow

UPDATE - without React hooks everything works...

## Issue

I am trying to build a single bundle (react component) for browser and node via webpack bundler for SSR purposes. Node should swallow that bundle as described here:

```js
const React = require("react");
const ReactDOMServer = require("react-dom/server");
const Test = require("./public/index.js").default; // ✅ React Component (works)

ReactDOMServer.renderToString(React.createElement(Test)); // Error
```

but an error appears:

> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body
> of a function component. This could happen for one of the following
> reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

BUT browser version works. However after adding `externals` into webpack configuration, the node version works and browser does not.

#### React component file before bundling via webpack bundler

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function Test() {
  const [_, __] = React.useState(1);

  return React.createElement("div", null, _); // ✅ <div>1</div> (works)
}

if (typeof window !== "undefined") { // because of UMD
  ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(Test), document.getElementById("index")); // ✅ (works)
}

export default Test; // ✅
```

#### webpack configuration file

```
...
{
  entry: "./index.js", // File described above
  // The node version will work but the browser version will stop working after uncommenting the lines below
  //
  // externals: {
  //   react: 'react',
  //   'react-dom': 'react-dom'
  // },
  mode: "development",
  output: {
    filename: "index.js",
    globalObject: "this",
    libraryTarget: "umd",
    path: path.resolve("./public"),
    publicPath: "",
  },
},
...
```

Comment: Why are you wrapping the `Test` component with `React.createElement`?

Comment: @Chris because it is necessary... `ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<Test />)` === `ReactDOMServer.renderToString(React.createElement(Test))` without JSX :-)

Comment: Ah, I've never seen it like this!

Answer (score 0):

> BUT browser version works. However after adding externals into webpack configuration, the node version works and browser does not.

This maybe considered a workaround, but you could use two separate webpack configs, one for the node and the other for the browser version.

Edit:
Also for the node version not working: You're only have a `require` for ReactDOMServer, but not for ReactDom itself, maybe that is a problem, too.

I'm using this form, maybe give it a try:

```
externals: {
                "react": {
                    "commonjs": "react",
                    "commonjs2": "react",
                    "amd": "react",
                    "root": "React"
                },
                "react-dom": {
                    "commonjs": "react-dom",
                    "commonjs2": "react-dom",
                    "amd": "react-dom",
                    "root": "ReactDom"
                },
            },
```

Comment: Ok but now I need to import `react` and `react-dom` from CDN on browser side

Comment: Why? You can still bundle them with your browser webpack config, where you just don't use the `externals` object.